# How to compare values from different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I want to compare like so:

```
dataframe 1
ID Name City  Mail          Time
1  Tata Paris toto@mail.com 22-05-19
2  root Paris root@mail.com 22-05-18
3  Toto Paris toto@mail.com 22-05-17
```

```
Dataframe 2
ID Name City  Mail          Time
1  Toto Paris toto@mail.com 22-05-17
2  Tata Paris toto@mail.com 22-05-17
3  Tutu Paris toto@mail.com 22-05-17
```

I want a data Frame 3 that show the differences

```
DataFrame 3
ID Attrbute DF1           DF2
1  Name     Tata          Toto
1  Time     22-05-19      22-05-17
2  Name     root          Tata
2  Mail     root@mail.com toto@mail.com
2  Time     22-05-18      22-05-17
```

What I have done, I merged the two data frame on ID

```
 def df_merge(df1, df2):
        df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='ID',how= 'inner')
        return df3
```

After that I create columns with true or false when I find the identical variable

```
   def diff_post_merge(df1):
        for column in df1:
            if column != 'ID':
                df1[column + "_check?"] = np.where(df1[column] == df1[column[:-2] + "_y"], True, False)
        return df1
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe thank to true and false indicator:

```
ID Attrbute DF1           DF2
1  Name     Tata          Toto
1  Time     22-05-19      22-05-17
2  Name     root          Tata
2  Mail     root@mail.com toto@mail.com
2  Time     22-05-18      22-05-17
```

If you need anymore information I can provide.

Comment: I achieve to do somethng but it work on index, not on ID... How can I do? my ID are not number....

Answer (score 0):

First, create the two data frames:

```
columns = ('ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Mail', 'Time')
data = [(1, 'Tata', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-19'), 
        (2, 'root', 'Paris', 'root@mail.com', '22-05-18'), 
        (3, 'Toto', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

columns = ('ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Mail', 'Time')
data = [(1, 'Toto', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17'), 
        (2, 'Tata', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17'), 
        (3, 'Tutu', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Second, re-shape each of the data frames (i.e., column labels become row labels) and then merge on the index, which is (ID + Attribute):

```
df_comp = pd.concat([df1.stack().rename('df1'), 
                     df2.stack().rename('df2')], 
                    axis=1)
```

Third, compare corresponding entries (same => true, different => false).  Then select only entries with differences, and print the results:

```
df_comp['same'] = (df_comp['df1'] == df_comp['df2'])

result = (df_comp[ ~ df_comp['same'] ]
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={'level_0': 'ID', 'level_1': 'Attribute'})
         )

print(result)

   ID Attribute            df1            df2   same
0   0      Name           Tata           Toto  False
1   0      Time       22-05-19       22-05-17  False
2   1      Name           root           Tata  False
3   1      Mail  root@mail.com  toto@mail.com  False
4   1      Time       22-05-18       22-05-17  False
5   2      Name           Toto           Tutu  False
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way to approach this and looks really good! Not sure what OP wanted, but it seems like you could happily keep the index as a MultiIndex of `ID` and `Attribute`. And if you don't want to have the 'same' column you can get the result all in one step: `result = df_comp[df_comp['df1'] != df_comp['df2']]`

Answer (score 0):

## Update using pandas 1.1.0+  Using [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#comparing-two-dataframe-or-two-series-and-summarizing-the-differences)

Using @jsmart setup:

```
columns = ('ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Mail', 'Time')
data = [(1, 'Tata', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-19'), 
        (2, 'root', 'Paris', 'root@mail.com', '22-05-18'), 
        (3, 'Toto', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

columns = ('ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Mail', 'Time')
data = [(1, 'Toto', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17'), 
        (2, 'Tata', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17'), 
        (3, 'Tutu', 'Paris', 'toto@mail.com', '22-05-17')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

We can use `compare` and reshape with `stack`:

```
df1.set_index('ID')\
   .compare(df2.set_index('ID'))\
   .stack(0).rename_axis(['ID','Attributes'])\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID Attributes          other           self
0   1       Name           Toto           Tata
1   1       Time       22-05-17       22-05-19
2   2       Mail  toto@mail.com  root@mail.com
3   2       Name           Tata           root
4   2       Time       22-05-17       22-05-18
5   3       Name           Tutu           Toto
```

---

Let's use a boolean matrix created by comparing dataframes, then `mask` each of the dataframes and `stack`, Lastly, `pd.concat` results with `keys` parameter:

```
m = df1 == df2
df1s = df1.mask(m).stack()
df2s = df2.mask(m).stack()
df_out = pd.concat([df1s, df2s], keys=['df1', 'df2'], axis=1)
df_out
```

Output:

```
                  df1            df2
0 Name           Tata           Toto
  Time       22-05-19       22-05-17
1 Name           root           Tata
  Mail  root@mail.com  toto@mail.com
  Time       22-05-18       22-05-17
2 Name           Toto           Tutu
```